# How to Test a Form with Multiple Submit

Tags: symfony, testing, automated-tests, symfony4, symfony-forms

I have a form with 2 submit

```
// src/Form/FooType.php
$builder
    ->add('mainsubmit', SubmitType::class, [])
    ->add('extrasubmit', SubmitType::class, [])
```

In my controller, I do some different treatment depending of the submit pressed

```
// src/Controller/FooController.php
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    if ($form->get('extrasubmit')->isClicked()) {
        // do some extra stuff
    }
```

When I click on the extra button, I can see it the symfony Profiler in the request `POST` parameters `"extrasubmit" => ""`.
**Everything works fine.**

I'm doing functional tests with the crawler.
Without trying to submit with the extra submit, it works fine, so we can assume my test doesn't have a typo.

**How can I simulate the click on the extra submit ?**

First Try:

```
$form = $crawler->filter('form')->form();
// [...]
$form['my_form_name[extrasubmit]'] = true;
$httpClient->submit($form);
// => InvalidArgumentException: Unreachable field "extrasubmit"
```

Second Try:

```
$form->get('my_form_name[extrasubmit]')->setValue("");
// => InvalidArgumentException: Unreachable field "extrasubmit"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like often when have trouble with the `DomCrawler`, it is much better to fo throught `$form->getPhpValues()` which returns an array of values.
Then you just have to mimic the values given in the request

```
$values = $form->getPhpValues();
$values['my_form_name']['extrasubmit'] = '';

$httpClient->request(
    $form->getMethod(),
    $form->getUri(),
    $values
);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/80e38d27ee145f6d0f4f2fa554a4f85ca634f729/src/Symfony/Component/DomCrawler/Form.php#L379) you can set the button via the `setNode($domnode)` method on the form. Sadly there is no function to find the nodes on the form object itself (since the node doesn't have to be a descendant of the form, that might not even help much).

So I guess something similar to

```
$form->setNode($crawler->filter('#extrasubmitbutton-id')[0]);
```

would set the submit button...